# Setting Image Exactly in Center

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have divided Screen in 4 horizontal and two vertical portion.I am using Linear Layout to display the ImageView and TextView.I am not able to set the imageView exactly in center of the Linear layout.

**home_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <include layout="@layout/appbar_layout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#156C7F"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
            android:text="Branch Office : Dhankuta"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:text="Tuesday - 4 April, 2017"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="10sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <!--  Main Linear Layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#DFDFDF"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--   first Frame -->


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- first row first column -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@mipmap/saving"></ImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Saving Collection"
                    android:textColor="#494949"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <!-- first row second column -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView  **i have made changes here**
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@mipmap/loancollection"></ImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Loan Collection"
                    android:textColor="#494949"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- 2nd frame  -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- Second row first column -->

            <LinearLayout       **i have made changes here**
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"

                    android:src="@mipmap/dailysaving"></ImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Daily Saving"
                    android:textColor="#494949"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
               />


            </LinearLayout>


            <!-- Second row Second column -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/memberenrollment"></ImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Member Enrollment"
                    android:textColor="#494949"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- 3rd frame  -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- Third row First column -->


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/cashincashout"></ImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Cash In-Out "
                    android:textColor="#494949"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- Third row Second column -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/collectorledger"></ImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Collector Ledger "
                    android:textColor="#494949"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- 4th frame  -->


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <!-- Fourth row First column -->


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/summary"></ImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Summary"
                    android:textColor="#494949"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Fourth row Second column -->


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/officesync"></ImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Office Sync"
                    android:textColor="#494949"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- 4th frame end  -->


    </LinearLayout>   <!-- main frame end Layout -->


</LinearLayout>
```

I have made changes on the first row first column and on the 1st row 2nd column

> **I want the imageView to lie exactly in Center of the Linear Layout and then the Text will Adjust on the remaining portion.**How can this issue be solved?

Comment: I recommend you to use **Relative Layout** instead. Its easy to work with relative layout

Comment: cant there any alternative with Linear Layout?

Comment: Why do you need "top | center" for each image? If you want to set the center in LinearLayout just set android:layout_gravity="center"

Otherwise, we can use RelativeLayout

Comment: I have mentioned that i have changes on the first row (1,2)column mate.not on other for this moment.(the other are not changed just for check)

Comment: Is it Strict to use Linear layout

Comment: No. mate its not strict.I have done this so far.if i can achieve my requirement with linear Layout ,then why i have to move on other thinking. if I cant achieve with linear i could jump on relative

Comment: @pzy64 i have changed to relative layout.but  when i use two view the one is not fitted exactly in center

Comment: in image view set **android:layout_centerInParent="true"**

Comment: in textview that is below the imageview set **android:layout_below="@id/ID_OF_IMAGEVIEW"**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142161/discussion-between-ghimire-and-pzy64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**UseBelowCode**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="#156C7F"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
        android:text="Branch Office : Dhankuta"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:text="Tuesday - 4 April, 2017"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<!--  Main Linear Layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#DFDFDF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--   first Frame -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- first row first column -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/conference_room"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Saving Collection"
                android:textColor="#494949"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- first row second column -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/conference_room"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Loan Collection"
                android:textColor="#494949"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- 2nd frame  -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- Second row first column -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/conference_room"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Daily Saving"
                android:textColor="#494949"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Second row Second column -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/conference_room"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Member Enrollment"
                android:textColor="#494949"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    <!-- 3rd frame  -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- Third row First column -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/conference_room"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Cash In-Out "
                android:textColor="#494949"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Third row Second column -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/conference_room"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Collector Ledger "
                android:textColor="#494949"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- 4th frame  -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- Fourth row First column -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/conference_room"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Summary"
                    android:textColor="#494949"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <!-- Fourth row Second column -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/conference_room"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Office Sync"
                    android:textColor="#494949"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- 4th frame end  -->
</LinearLayout>   <!-- main frame end Layout -->
```

Comment: nothing will change in layout, if you add ID's or not

Comment: if i have to set the textfield not in the Bottom ? then the Below iD should be used.I think so

Comment: thanks .your LOgic is good.But How can this be Achieved with the LinearLayout???can't i did this with LinearLayout ir NOt???\

Comment: You can do this by using weights, I have added answer, check it

Answer (score 1):

**LinearLayout Instead of RelativeLayout**

```
<!-- first row first column -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sjkashjkasd"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/conference_room"
                android:layout_weight="1.9"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/asdlkjl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Saving Collection"
                android:textColor="#494949"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Linearlayout` to match your requirement use below code:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_border_help"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="HELLO"
            android:textColor="@color/color_black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_border_help"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="HELLO"
            android:textColor="@color/color_black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_border_help"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="HELLO"
            android:textColor="@color/color_black" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I have worked same as your idea.Now i am going with Relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in LinearLayout

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: I have already added in the Linear layout.please check above layout code.
ist row first and second column

Comment: i didnt get you mate

Answer (score 0):

You can set the gravity of the Linear Layout that is holding your views to centre, this way

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#156C7F"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
            android:text="Branch Office : Dhankuta"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:text="Tuesday - 4 April, 2017"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="10sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

This simply means that any child elements inside of your linearLayout should be defaultly placed at the exact center of the layout. When you define the gravity for the linearlayout there will be no need to define elements layout_gravity, it will be automatically set to center.

Comment: if i have used two field i.e textView and ImageVIew.How can the one be put exactly in center and another below the centered one?

Comment: if want so go to RelativeLayout

Comment: I am using Relative Layout but not achieving

Comment: If you want the textview below the image view, all you have to do is set the linearlayout orientation to vertical. Note this is the Linear layout containing the imageview and the textview.